# Nodejs: Don't run `new class` with export

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

this is my config:

```
const one = new one()
const two = new two()

export default {
  one,
  two
}
```

And this is my classes:

```
export class one {
  constructor () {
    console.log("one");
  }
}

export class two {
  constructor () {
    console.log("two");
  }
}
```

And this is my setup:

```
import runner from "./";
runner.one
```

Why after call `runner.one`, also `runner.two` running?!

I want to run only `runner.one`

Comment: `const one = new one()` never works, it will always result in a *ReferenceError*. Did you name your actual variables differently?

Answer (score 0):

It happens in here:

```
const one = new one()
const two = new two()
```

cause You defined in `constructor()` methods of both classes to do `console.log`

when You call `new ClassNameHere()` it executes `constructor()`

You could simply export classes instead of instantiating them:

runners.mjs

```
export class one {
  constructor () {
    console.log("one");
  }
}

export class two {
  constructor () {
    console.log("two");
  }
}
```

executor.mjs

```
import * as runners from "./runners";

const one = new runner.one();
```

OR name classes CapitalizedCamelCased:

runners.mjs

```
export class RunnerOne {
  constructor () {
    console.log("one");
  }
}

export class RunnerTwo {
  constructor () {
    console.log("two");
  }
}
```

executor.mjs

```
import {RunnerOne} from "./runners";

const one = new RunnerOne();
```

Comment: I understand. how can I fix it?

Comment: @ali learn OOP in JS. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T-HGdc8L-7w  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ex11_N-Fn94

Answer (score 0):

It's happing because you're instantiating both of them globally using `const` specifier.

When you do this, the code calls the constructor of each class as soon as it comes across instantiation (`new` keyword).

```
const one = new one()
const two = new two()

export default {
  one,
  two
}
```

If this is not what you want, and you want them to initialize separately, there could be multiple ways to achieve that.

One is to separately instantiate them, before you access them. (You could use it in a situation where you still need access to instantiated object inside the class you're instantiating them in). Something like this:

Class that contains one and two:

(assuming you define your classes in file `onetwo.mjs`)

```
import * as ot from "./onetwo.mjs";

let one;
let two;

function instantiateOne() {
  one = new ot.one();
}

function instantiateTwo() {
  two = new ot.two();
}

export default {
  one,
  two,
  instantiateOne,  // expose methods needed to create instances
  instantiateTwo,
}
```

Class that uses above:

```
import runner from "./";

runner.instantiateOne(); // this will only create instance of 'one'

runner.one; // accessing one
```

Of course there are other ways, and it might need more changes to make it work in your project, but this is one of the patterns. Just be aware when using such a strategy, you either always check before using the object (`one` or `two`) that they have been instantiated, or you ensure you do it at start.

NOTE: This is just to give you an idea. This isn't a concrete implementation. If you do want to implement something like this, you'll have to handle all edge cases (example, prevent re-initialization etc.)